# Count empty file upload controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

In a dynamically generated set of file upload controls:

```
<input type="file" name="archivos[]">
<input type="file" name="archivos[]">
<input type="file" name="archivos[]">
// ...
```

... I can easily count the non-empty ones:

```
// Works fine
var nonEmptyCount = $("input[type='file'][name='archivos[]'][value!='']").length;
```

However, when I try to count the *empty* ones (what I actually need) the selector never matches anything:

```
// Always zero
var emptyCount = $("input[type='file'][name='archivos[]'][value='']").length;
```

I can't believe I need this cumbersome code:

```
// Works but ugly
var emptyCount = $("input[type='file'][name='archivos[]']").length -
    $("input[type='file'][name='archivos[]'][value!='']").length;
```

What bit am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have an explanation (and I'll immediately accept any answer that provides one) but the root cause seems to be using the generic *attribute equals selector* to find the controls:

```
$("input[type='file']")
```

If I use the [jQuery extension short-cut](http://api.jquery.com/file-selector/), everything else works as expected:

```
$("input:file")
```

As per the docs:

- Both selectors should behave identically
- `[type='file']` should perform better

... so there must be a bug somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to check if value is empty inside an iterator like:

```js
$("#findEmpty").on("click", function() {
  var count = 0;
  $(":file[name='archivos[]']").each(function() {
    if (this.value == "") {
      count++;
    }
  });
  alert(count);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="archivos[]" />
<input type="file" name="archivos[]" />
<input type="file" name="archivos[]" />
<input type="file" name="archivos[]" />
<input type="file" name="archivos[]" />
<input type="file" name="archivos[]" />
<input type='button' value='Check Empty' id='findEmpty' />
```

Comment: Funny... The important bit seems to be using `:file` instead of `[type='file']`. With that little change, my original code seems to work as expected :-?

Comment: Whatever, `.val()` returns «the current value of the **first element** in the set».

Answer (score 0):

You can filter them this way:

```
var emptyOne = $("input[type='file'][name='archivos[]']").filter(function () {
        return $(this).val() == "";
    });
```

```js
$(function () {

    var emptyOne = $("input[type='file'][name='archivos[]']").filter(function () {
        return $(this).val() == "";
    });

    alert(emptyOne.length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="archivos[]">
<input type="file" name="archivos[]">
<input type="file" name="archivos[]">
```

[EXAMPLE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ydcjugg1/)